# Nginx constantly redirecting

Tags: docker, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm deploying an app first time like this, running a FE container separate from the BE. Currently, this setup just ends up redirecting endlessly. Any idea why?

server nginx for that domain

```
server {
      listen 80;
      server_name domain;
      return 301 https://domain$request_uri;

      client_max_body_size 0;
}

 server {
      server_name domain;

      error_log /var/log/nginx/dom_error.log;
      access_log /var/log/nginx/dom_access.log;

      location / {
          proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header Host $host;
          proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1904;
          add_header  X-Host $host;
      }
      
        listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
  }
```

nginx for that app

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        proxy_pass http://fe:3000;

        proxy_redirect off;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }

    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://be:8000/api;
    }

    location /mongo {
        proxy_pass http://mongodb:8081;
    }
}
```

Any clue what is wrong here?

Comment: It redirects to what? `https` to `https`? Did you check that in  Inspect Elements / Network tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this issue was that nginx conf was not properly reset and changes weren't propagated. This config works properly. Remember to reload after you edit your configuration!

Answer (score 0):

A bit nonobvious configuration for me, your ide might need more specific explanation, but as far as there is only one redirect `return 301 https://domain$request_uri;` I assume that you could try different way:

```
if ($scheme = "http") {
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

Also I don't get `client_max_body_size 0;` config entry, do you understand why is it there?

Comment: `client_max_body_size 0;` was a type, it was in the wrong block, fixed it now